# How to send XML content with HttpClient.PostAsync?

Tags: c#, post, httpclient

I am trying to fulfill [this rest api](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/YTD5/Create+New+Work+Item):

```
public async Task<bool> AddTimetracking(Issue issue, int spentTime)
{
    // POST /rest/issue/{issue}/timetracking/workitem
    var workItem = new WorkItem(spentTime, DateTime.Now);
    var httpContent = new StringContent(workItem.XDocument.ToString());
    var requestUri = string.Format("{0}{1}issue/{2}/timetracking/workitem", url, YoutrackRestUrl, issue.Id);
    var respone = await httpClient.PostAsync(requestUri, httpContent);
    if (!respone.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        throw new InvalidUriException(string.Format("Invalid uri: {0}", requestUri));
    }

    return respone.IsSuccessStatusCode;
}
```

`workItem.XDocument` contains the following elements:

```xml
<workItem>
  <date>1408566000</date>
  <duration>40</duration>
  <desciption>test</desciption>
</workItem>
```

I am getting an error from the API: `Unsupported Media Type`

I really have no idea how to resolve this, help is greatly appreciated. How do I *marshall* an XML file via a HTTP POST URI, using `HttpClient`?

Comment: You calculate the date as seconds but the example in your link uses msec.

Comment: @L.B, changed it to miliseconds, no luck. I guess I am doing the wrong thing with the HttpContent. Unfortunately google doesn't help me much yet

Comment: P.S: when I set up firefox poster with the exact same parameters, it works. Not that much luck trying from C#.

Comment: bas, download [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and see the difference between firefox and your code..

Comment: @L.B, thx for the tip, I'll give that a go tomorrow.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

You might want to set the mediaType in StringContent like below:

```
var httpContent = new StringContent(workItem.XDocument.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml");
```

OR

```
var httpContent = new StringContent(workItem.XDocument.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml");
```

Comment: text/xml in my case

Comment: I know this answer is several years old but media type needed to be "text/xml" in my case as well.

Answer (score 28):

You could use

```
var respone = await httpClient.PostAsXmlAsync(requestUri, workItem);
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclientextensions_methods

Comment: Looks like a better solution than the accepted answer

Comment: This method is not there in asp.net core 3.1

Answer (score 7):

To use Matt Frear's solution you may need to add NuGet Package:
**Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client**

This brings in the extension methods so you can use:

```
var respone = await httpClient.PostAsXmlAsync<WorkItem>(requestUri, workItem);
```

This works for the newer .Net 5 so assume will work for asp.net core 3.1.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer doesn't include the XML declaration, which may or may not matter.  Below is a simple extension method for `XDocument` that prepends the XML declaration.  Otherwise, the technique is identical:

```
// Extension method
public static string ToStringWithDeclaration(this XDocument doc, string declaration = null)
{
    declaration ??= "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\r\n";
    return declaration + doc.ToString();
}

// Usage (XDocument -> string -> UTF-8 bytes)
var content = new StringContent(doc.ToStringWithDeclaration(), Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml");
var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("/someurl", content);
```

If you want, you can also skip the step of converting the `XDocument` to a `string` (which is UTF-16 encoded), and just go right to UTF-8 bytes:

```
// Extension method
public static ByteArrayContent ToByteArrayContent(
    this XDocument doc, XmlWriterSettings xmlWriterSettings = null)
{
    xmlWriterSettings ??= new XmlWriterSettings();
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream, xmlWriterSettings))
        {
            doc.Save(writer);
        }
        var content = new ByteArrayContent(stream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)stream.Length);
        content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/xml");
        return content;
    }
}

// Usage (XDocument -> UTF-8 bytes)
var content = doc.ToByteArrayContent();
var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("/someurl", content);

// To view the serialized XML as a string (for debugging), you'd have to do something like:
using var reader = new StreamReader(content.ReadAsStream());
string xmlStr = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

For a third option, `XDocument.Save`/`XmlWriter` can also output to a `string` via `StringBuilder` ([as shown in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xdocument.save)).  That is useful if you want a `string` but need control over formatting (such as whether to use indentation).  Just be aware that the XML declaration generated via this method will always say "utf-16" (regardless of `XmlWriterSettings.Encoding`), so you probably want to specify `XmlWriterSettings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true` and add the declaration manually afterward.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4533609/5405967) for some discussion of that issue.