# How can I make an HTTP request and send some xml data using POSTin c#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, post, http-post

I have to make a HTTP request with URL `https://{server}/apimember/services/rest/member/insertOrUpdateMember/{token}`

I have values of server and token
Now I need to send the xml as  data with some fields
The xml looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<synchroMember>
 <memberUID>{field1}:{value1}|{field2}:{value2}</memberUID>
 <dynContent>
 <entry>
  <key>{fieldNameA}</key>
  <value>{fieldValueA}</value>
 </entry>
 <entry>
  <key>{fieldNameB}</key>
  <value>{fieldValueB}</value>
 </entry>
 <entry>
  <key>{fieldNameC}</key>
  <value>{fieldValueC}</value>
 </entry>
</dynContent>
</synchroMember>`
```

I need to insert the values of  field1, fieldNameA, fieldNameB, fieldNameC.
Later I can read the response of the requested URL.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[try here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25352462/how-to-send-xml-content-with-httpclient-postasync/25352880#25352880)

```
var httpContent = new StringContent(workItem.XDocument.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml");
```

Comment: yes, i am aware of this but now, how do i need to send the values of the variables described in the xml/